# Why does my rails app raise a "database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, pg

I just updated my production rails app with Capistrano within a new gemset for ruby 2.2 and I got the following error :

```
/var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

This is my database.yml :

```
production:
  host: localhost
  port: xxxx
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: odpf
  pool: 5
  username: xxxxxx
  password: xxxxxx
```

I dont understand why I got this error as my database.yml didnt changed before and after the capisrano update.

All gems are stored into /var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems.

The pg gem for postgresql is present if I run a `bundle exec gem list`

My database is working as I can connect to it from psql with the user of database.yml : `\c odpf xxxxxx 127.0.0.1 xxxx`

So I don't understand what's going wrong.

This is also an extract of a bigger trace error when I run a `bundle exec rails c` :

```
/var/www/odpf/current$ bundle exec rails c
/var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
```

It is talking about a circular reference in ActiveSupport, maybe it helps to solve this ?

=== UPDATE ===

I just add test and development section to my database.yml and the error message did change. It seems rails believe he is in test mode :

```
bundle exec rails c

/var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/var/www/odpf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)
```

I can't figure out why this happen though ? Because I've got a `RailsEnv production` line in my virtual host, and it was working fine before capistrano update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact everything was correct.

About rails console, it always executes in developpement mode unless you ask specificaly for production parameter.

Concerning my issue, I had to stop postgresql, stop apache2, and modify my `.gitignore` file to track again the tmp/restart.txt file and make it part of my repository again (by copying it, deleting the old one, `git add -A`, `git push ...`).

Then start back postgresql and apache2.

Sorry for the question.